# What is the difference between project site templates PWA#0 or ProjectSite#0

Tags: 2013, 2010, site-collection, project-server

What is the difference between project site templates PWA#0 or ProjectSite#0 . Is PWA for 2010 and ProjectSite for 2013?

I am looking at creating site collection for project server using PowerShell.

```
$projectSite = New-SPSite -Url $projectSiteUrl  -OwnerAlias $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME -Template "PROJECTSITE#0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projectsite is new template introduced in the SharePpint 2013, that site does not required the Project server licensing. You can read in depth about this template [over here:](http://blog.fpweb.net/understanding-sharepoint-2013-project-site-template/#.VyOzMvkrKCg)

On the PWA templates called project web app which are part of Project Server( Project service Application) and required extra configuration. i.e project server configuration, provision project web app etc.

If you already have project server installed then use PWA#0.

Answer (score 2):

A project site, ProjectSite#0, is a standard SharePoint project site template.

A Project Web Access site, PWA#0, is a special template for those using Project Pro/Project Web Access for project management.

If you don't have anyone using MS Project, stick to ProjectSite#0 templates.